# First day and Last day of previous year

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to find the date of the end of previous year in Postgres.

This will give me the first day of previous year

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', now()- interval '1 year')
```

**returns** the correct result  #=> `2018-01-01 00:00:00`

But trying to remove 1day from the first day of the current year doesn't give me the last day of previous year:

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', now() - interval '1 day')
```

**returns** #=> `2018-01-01 00:00:00`

When I'm expecting it to be 2018-12-31

Still gives me the first day of the current year. Even if i remove 100 day it still returns the same result.

Same behavior for previous years:

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', now()- interval '2 year');
```

**returns** #=> `2017-01-01 00:00:00`  which is what I expect.

but :

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', now()- interval '1 year' - interval '1 day');
```

**returns** #=> `2018-01-01 00:00:00`  when I'm expecting `2017-12-31`

-- 
For future reference I'm posting this in 2019.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an order of operations issue. Truncate the date before subtracting:

```
SELECT date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '1 day';
SELECT date_trunc('year', now()- interval '1 year') - interval '1 day';
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)